# URLClassLoader slow under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a classpath directory containing about 30 jars. In my plain console application I am creating an `URLClassLoader` where I initialize it with the list of `URL`s pointing to all these jars.

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] {
    new URL("jar:file:/D:/Work/temp/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar!/"),
    new URL("jar:file:/D:/Work/temp/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/"),
    new URL("jar:file:/D:/Work/temp/jars/c3p0-0.9.1.jar!/"),
    ...
}
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(...);
etc...
```

Like this everything is working fine, taking a few milliseconds to load a single class from my `URLClassLoader`.

Now I take this snippet of code and make it run under Tomcat, e.g. triggered at a simple web request inside a servlet's `doGet()`. Surprisingly, the time lapse taken to load an average class becomes 10-15 times longer, making the whole initialization time inacceptable. The issue holds for at least Tomcat versions both 6 and 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely silly, but the issue has gone away after I rebooted my machine :) I am running Windows 7, Oracle JDK 1.6/1.7, Tomcat 6/7, the problem persisted for any combination of these. The profiler was showing me that it was `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile`'s `<init>` which was slowing down the whole stuff. Probably something went wrong with jars cache so that unnecessary initialization executed for every class requested from a jar.

**Update:**
I've found how to fix the issue with class loading being so slow and getting even slower as long as you are not rebooting your machine. Instead of using

```
new URL("jar:file:/D:/Work/temp/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar!/")
```

I've tried

```
new URL("file:/D:/Work/temp/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar")
```

The `URLClassloader` handles properly this kind of URLs as jars even without "jar" protocol being specified. However it drastically increased the performance! Still I don't know the exact reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try `new URLClassLoader(urls);`. Does this improve the performance?

Common and WebappX class loaders may affect the performance of loading a class. Please see following link for more details of Tomcat's Class Loader.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: No, it doesn't. This will only affect the value of parent classloader which will be the system classloader in your case, but it is the `findClass()` which takes so long, so the parent does not matter. Another notice: when I move all the jars in /WEB-INF/lib, they are loaded instantly by WebappClassLoader, just like inside the console app. I see that despite the WebappClassLoader extends URLClassLoader, it does not use its machinery to load classes, using some kind of its own instead. But I can't discern the principal difference.

Comment: Another observation: long filesystem paths (depth 10 or more) to jars take `URLClassLoader` about twice as longer to load classes as compared with short paths.